# CodeFirstInstallationService usage?

Tags: nopcommerce

I am new to Nopcommerce and I tried to find a way to update my database after modify some changes. I found this file name `CodeFirstInstallationService.cs` which is in the Service directory. My question is:

- What is the use of this file? Is it only run once in the first installation, or is run everytime I run the server?
- If I modify the content after installation, can the server be updated?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to find a way to update my database after modify some changes

First of all, nopCommerce doesn't provide migration update from the code anyway. You have to recreate the DB or you have to add it manually. Please check official doc at: [`Updating an existing entity. How to add a new property`](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1442499)

> What is the use of this file? Is it only run once in the first
>   installation, or is run everytime I run the server?

This service contains information that need to add at the time of installation. You can put the debug point and check if being called every time or not.

Hope this helps!